# При динамической загрузке, не работают часть скриптов?

Tags: content, ajax

Всем привет.
Я использую динамическую подгрузку контента.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getContent").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"content.html",
            cache:false,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $("#divContent").html("")
            },
            success:function(a){
                $("#divContent").html(a)
            }
        });

        return false
    })
});
```

При этом часть скриптов после загрузки не работают.
Любые идеи?

Comment: Смотреть [``.bind()``](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [``.live()``](http://api.jquery.com/live/) и пользоваться [``.on()``](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: посмотреть консоль для начала

Comment: А вообще похоже на отборочный тур в шоу "Телепаты".

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Любые идеи?

Идея одна - это тот случай, когда я безоговорочно отправляю в мануалы. Даже на этом форуме подобных тем просто море. Объясню: jQuery достаточно динамически развивается и, если вы ориентируетесь на какие-то сторонние, пусть даже хорошие, материалы в инете, то некоторые методы описанные там год назад, на сегодняшний день устарели, а свежее почерпнуть - можно только на официальном сайте.

[@xEdelweiss](/users/7017/xedelweiss) правильно сказал по поводу метода [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Я бы просто добавил, что надо смотреть на этот метод не только, как объединяющий устаревшие **.bind()**, **.live()** и **.delegate()**, но и в сторону делегированной обработки событий. Тут всё просто и схематически можно представить так:

```
$('ближайший_родительский_и_статический_элемент').on('событие', 'динамически_подгруженный_елемент', function(){
    // действия, которые надо выполнить
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить что суть в том, что сначала описаны какие-либо события для элементов, потом подгружаются новые элементы и для них эти события не работают.
Если проблема в этом, то
Когда вы пишете $('.myclass').action(function(e){...})
То код исполняется один раз при загрузке страницы и всё.
Т.е. для существующих элементов события создались. Когда же добавляются элементы, то для них событие не создано и его нужно переопределить в функции успешного ответа

```
success:function(data){
$('#myDataContainer').html(data)
$('.myclass').action(function(e){...}
}
```